# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{r=1} ^x re^\frac{r}{x}}{x^2}$ without using L-Hospital rule?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to evaluate the following limit of the indeterminate form "$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$".

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{r=1} ^x re^\frac{r}{x}}{x^2}$$
$$OR$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^\frac{1}{x} + 2e^\frac{2}{x} +3e^\frac{3}{x} +4e^\frac{4}{x} +5e^\frac{5}{x}+\ldots+xe^\frac{x}{x}}{x^2}$$

The answer to this limit is unknown to me as I myself framed this question by chance which I'm unable to solve now. Of course it's possible that this question might already exist for long time(but I have not seen anywhere yet).

Your nice help towards the solution to this problem will be highly appreciable.

**NOTE-1:** I'm a high school student.
**NOTE-2:** Use of *L'Hospital* is not allowed.

**UPDATE:** Folks are saying that this problem is quite tough for a high school student but to your surprise I’ve found the solution & it’s quite easy and I've written the answer below in answers section. The answer to the problem is 1(one) ([answer proof 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%22Infinity%20%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limitvariable%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limitfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28%E2%88%91_1%20%5Ex%28r%28e%29%5E%28r%2Fx%29%29%29%2Fx%5E2%22), [answer proof 2](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gdyyld8sne))

Comment: What does the sum mean? Does it mean that $x$ is an integer there? If so, you can't use l'Hospital rule since you're in the discrete case. The discrete analogue is called Stolz Theorem

Comment: Use `x\to\infty` for the output $x\to\infty$. (:

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but I think the correct form is: _solution_ **to** _a problem_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this probel is quite **SIMPLE** as oppposed to others who are claiming it to be tough for a high school student....

the limit to be evaluated is.....

$$\lim_{x\to∞}\Big(\frac{e^\frac{1}{x}+ 2e^\frac{2}{x}+3e^\frac{3}{x}+4e^\frac{4}{x}+.....+xe^\frac{x}{x}}{x^2}\Big)$$

By subsituting $e^\frac{1}{x}=t$
$$\lim_{x\to∞}\Big(\frac{t+ 2t^{2}+3t^{3}+4t^{4}+.....+xt^{x}}{x^2}\Big)$$ $$\tag*{$...3$}$$
to keep things simple let us first calculatethe value of  $ t+ 2t^{2}+3t^{3}+4t^{4}+.....+xt^{x} $

$$S=t+ 2t^{2}+3t^{3}+4t^{4}+.....+xt^{x} $$ $$\tag*{$...1$}$$

dividing both sides by $t$

$$\frac{S}{t}=1+ 2t^{1}+3t^{2}+4t^{3}+.....+xt^{x-1}$$ $$\tag*{$...2$}$$

Subtarcting 1 from 2
$$S\Big(\frac{1-t}{t}\Big)=1+ t^{1}+t^{2}+t^{3}+.....+t^{x-1}-xt^x$$

Using the sum of geometric progression
$$S\Big(\frac{1-t}{t}\Big)=\frac{t^x-1}{t-1}-xt^x$$
$$S\Big(\frac{1-t}{t}\Big)=\frac{t^x-1-xt^{x+1}+xt^x}{t-1}$$
$$S=\frac{t^{x+1}-t-xt^{x+2}+xt^{x+1}}{-(t-1)^2}$$

Substituting back $t=e^\frac{1}{x}$
$$S=\frac{-e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}+e^{\frac{1}{x}}+xe^{1+\frac{2}{x}}-xe^{1+\frac{1}{x}
}}{(e^\frac{1}{x}-1)^2}$$

Putting S back in the equation 3

$$\lim_{x\to∞}\frac{-e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}+e^{\frac{1}{x}}+xe^{1+\frac{2}{x}}-xe^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2(e^\frac{1}{x}-1)^2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to∞}\frac{-e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}+e^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{xe^{1+\frac{1}{x}}(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)x}{x}}{x^2\frac{(e^\frac{1}{x}-1)^2}{x^2}x^2}$$

By applying the standard limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log_{e} a$$

$$\frac{-e+1+e}{1}$$
$$1$$

$$CHEERS...$$

Answer (score 3):

If you define
$$f(x)=xe^x$$
then the sum 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n^2}ke^{k/n}$$
is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1nf\left(\frac kn\right)$$
which tends to
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=(1-1)e^1-(0-1)e^0=1$$

NOTE: this problem is very difficult for a high school student.

Answer (score 1):

As @ajotatxe already wrote, *"this problem is very difficult for a high school student"*

Considering
$$S_x=\frac{\sum_{r=1} ^x re^\frac{r}{x}}{x^2}$$ the numerator is "just"
$$\sum_{r=1} ^x re^\frac{r}{x}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(e^{\frac{1}{x}+1} x-e
   x-e+1\right)}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)^2}$$ Using Taylor expansion (this is even less trivial than L'Hospital rule) for large values of $x$, you would have
$$\sum_{r=1} ^x re^\frac{r}{x}=x^2+\frac{e
   }{2}x+\frac{2e-1}{12}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ making
$$S_x=1+\frac{e   }{2x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Just for the fun of it, use your pocket calculator for $x=5$; you will get
$$S_5=\frac{1}{25} \left(e^{1/5}+2 e^{2/5}+3 e^{3/5}+4 e^{4/5}+5 e\right)\approx 1.287$$ while the above expansion would give $1+\frac{e}{10}\approx 1.272$

Comment: By the way Answer is one

Comment: @pRSmHJN1. Yes if $x\to \infty$. I gave you a way to *estimate* the partial sums.